# Why is it when I reassign a value to a variable inside a function, the variable becomes undefined and I get a type error?

Tags: javascript

My program is similar to Battleship where you pick random squares to strike down two ships and they display as hit or miss. I want to make it where if I destroy a ship, it displays a picture of the ship in the Graveyard. It worked initially when I had hardcoded position values on where the ships were, but once I randomized the values and had to reassign the new values to my global variables, the javascript to css broke. And I got a type error, telling me that my global variable was undefined.

There's a section in my code called Part 1 which contains my global variables.

```
//PART 1
//var skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:11, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 12, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};
var skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:tinyBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: tinyBox2, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};

//var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:14, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 15, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: 16, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};
var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:largeBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: largeBox2, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: largeBox3, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};

var fleet = [skiff, battleship];
```

and Part 2

```
//PART 2
fleet = [skiff, battleship];
```

where if you have this line in code in place, it reassigns the global variables the randomized value rather the default values of the ships. Part 2 is also in a function call MakeNewBoats which creates random values for variables, skiff and battleship, and into their hitboxes. However in return, the function called showGraveyard which displays the image of the boat when the boat is destroyed no longer works.

```
function showGraveyard(boats){

    for(var j=0; j<boats.length; j++){
        var boatDead = true;
    
        for(var x=0; x<boats[j].spaces.length; x++){
                if(boats[j].spaces[x].hitBefore==false){
                    boatDead = false;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(boatDead==true){
            boats[j].elem.style.display="block";
        }
    }

}
```

The boat parameter is trying to get the fleet array variable to adjust the css of the proper ship but is being sent undefined. But if you comment Part 2 out,

```
//PART 2
//fleet = [skiff, battleship];
```

the program successfully displays the ship once the ship is destroyed. But the ship's values are not randomized and instead take on hard coded default values from here again.

```
//PART 1
//var skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:11, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 12, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};
var skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:tinyBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: tinyBox2, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};

//var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:14, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 15, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: 16, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};
var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:largeBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: largeBox2, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: largeBox3, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a type error.

**Uncaught TypeError: boats[j].elem.style is undefined**

This is my whole program for Battleship.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Battleships</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        
        #title{
            font-text:25px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        
        #victoryText{
            font-size: 15px;
            background-color: yellow;
            width:45%
            float:left; 
        }
        
        #gameTable{
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border:1px solid gray;
            width:45%;
            float:left;
        }
        #displayId{
            font-size: 15px;
            background-color: yellow;
            width:45%
            float:left; 
        }
        
        .titleRow{
            background-color: rgb(201, 201, 201);
            border:1px solid rgb(201, 201, 201);
        }
        .landRow{
            background-color: rgb(255, 234, 204);
            border:1px solid rgb(255, 234, 204);
        }
        .waterRow{
            background-color: rgb(150,150,255);
            border:1px solid rgb(4,130,255);
        }
        .appt {
            background-color:rgb(255,80,80);
        }
        
        #button{
            margin-top: 15px;
            clear:left;
            float:left;
            background-color:pink;
        }
    
        
            
        #graveyard {
            float: right;
            width: 30%;
            height: 40%;
            margin-left: 30px;
            border: 1px double rgb(85, 0, 255);
            background-color: rgb(163, 117, 255);
         }

    
        .deadShips{
            display:none;
            clear:right;
            float: right;
            margin-right:30px;
            width: auto%;
            height: auto%;
            border: 1px solid #22FF6C;
            background-color:#8DFFB3;
        }
          
        td, th{
        border:1px solid black;
        padding:5px;
        height:10px;
        }
        
    </style>
        
    <script>

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//LIBRARY OF FUNCTIONS
//showGraveyard
function showGraveyard(boats){

    for(var j=0; j<boats.length; j++){
        var boatDead = true;
    
        for(var x=0; x<boats[j].spaces.length; x++){
                if(boats[j].spaces[x].hitBefore==false){
                    boatDead = false;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(boatDead==true){
            boats[j].elem.style.display="block";
        }
    }

}

function checkShot(fireShot,boats){
    
    for(var j=0; j<boats.length; j++){
        for(var i=0; i<boats[j].spaces.length; i++){
                if(fireShot==boats[j].spaces[i].hitbox){
                    if(boats[j].spaces[i].hitBefore){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        boats[j].spaces[i].hitBefore=true;
                        showGraveyard(boats);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

function checkForWinner(boats){

    for(var j=0; j<boats.length; j++){
        for(var x=0; x<boats[j].spaces.length; x++){
                if(boats[j].spaces[x].hitBefore==false){
                    return false;
                }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function makeNewBoats(){
    var tinyStart = parseInt(Math.random()*(20-11)+11)-1;
    
    var tinyBox = [tinyStart, tinyStart+1];
    
    console.log("tinyBox: "+tinyBox);
    
    var largeStart = Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-12)+12)-2;
    
    var largeBox = [largeStart, largeStart+1, largeStart+2];
    
    console.log("largeBox: "+largeBox);
    
    for(var j=0; j<tinyBox.length; j++){
        for(var x=0; x<largeBox.length; x++){
            
            while(tinyBox[j]==largeBox[x]){
            
                    j=0;
                    
                    x=0;
                    
                    largeStart = Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-12)+12)-2;
    
                    largeBox = [largeStart, largeStart+1, largeStart+2];
                        
                    console.log("new largeBox: "+largeBox);
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log("final tinyBox: "+tinyBox);
    
    console.log("final largeBox: "+largeBox);
    
    return[tinyBox,largeBox];
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//GLOBAL VARIABLES

//create boats, boats will have values assigned to spaces, all of these boats will be put in a fleet, id for button clicked on check to see if one of the ids is one of the spaces, match remove from list of spaces, so the boat has fewer active elements, and update screen accordingly, and once removed every single space removed, you can start working on making the boat look sunk and in graveyard (hardcode ships)


var tinyBox1 = 11;
var tinyBox2 = 12;
    
var largeBox1 = 14;
var largeBox2 = 15;
var largeBox3 = 16;

var turnCounter = 0;

//PART 1
//var skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:11, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 12, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};
var skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:tinyBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: tinyBox2, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};

//var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:14, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 15, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: 16, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};
var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:largeBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: largeBox2, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: largeBox3, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};

var fleet = [skiff, battleship];

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

    
//MAIN PROGRAM
/** setRowHandlers take the class names of the odd and even rows in a table and gives each class mouseover and mouseout handlers that toggle the background color. */


function makeNewBoats(){
    var tinyStart = parseInt(Math.random()*(20-11)+11)-1;
    
    var tinyBox = [tinyStart, tinyStart+1];
    
    console.log("tinyBox: "+tinyBox);
    
    var largeStart = Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-12)+12)-2;
    
    var largeBox = [largeStart, largeStart+1, largeStart+2];
    
    console.log("largeBox: "+largeBox);
    
    for(var j=0; j<tinyBox.length; j++){
        for(var x=0; x<largeBox.length; x++){
            
            while(tinyBox[j]==largeBox[x]){
            
                    j=0;
                    
                    x=0;
                    
                    largeStart = Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-12)+12)-2;
    
                    largeBox = [largeStart, largeStart+1, largeStart+2];
                        
                    console.log("new largeBox: "+largeBox);
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log("final tinyBox: "+tinyBox);
    
    console.log("final largeBox: "+largeBox);
    
    tinyBox1 = tinyBox[0];
    tinyBox2 = tinyBox[1];
    
    largeBox1 = largeBox[0];
    largeBox2 = largeBox[1];
    largeBox3 = largeBox[2];
    
    skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:tinyBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: tinyBox2, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};

    //var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:14, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 15, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: 16, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};
    battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:largeBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: largeBox2, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: largeBox3, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};
    //PART 2
    fleet = [skiff, battleship];
}



window.onload = function(){
    
    fleet[0].elem=document.getElementById(fleet[0].name);
    fleet[1].elem=document.getElementById(fleet[1].name);
    
    setRowHandlers("square");
    
    makeNewBoats();

}



function validate(buttonId, boats, displayId, victoryText){

    var fireShot = parseInt(buttonId.substring(1));
    
    turnCounter++;
    console.log(turnCounter);
    
    var boatHit = checkShot(fireShot, boats);
    console.log(boatHit+"boathit");
    if(boatHit){
        document.getElementById(buttonId).innerHTML="hit";
    }else{
        document.getElementById(buttonId).innerHTML="miss";
    }
        
    if (boatHit){
        var message ="It's a HIT!! You have used "+turnCounter+" shots.";
        document.getElementById(displayId).innerHTML=message;
        console.log(checkForWinner(boats)+"winner");
        var fleetSunk = checkForWinner(boats);
        
        if(fleetSunk){
            document.getElementById(victoryText).innerHTML = "</br>CONGRATS! All boats have been sunk.";
        }
    }else{
        var message ="It's a miss. You have used "+turnCounter+" shots.";
        document.getElementById(displayId).innerHTML=message;
    }
    
}

function mouseOverRiver(elem){
        if(elem.innerHTML=="hit"){
            elem.style.backgroundColor="red";
        }else if(elem.innerHTML=="miss"){
            elem.style.backgroundColor="green"; 
        }else{
            elem.style.backgroundColor="blue";
        }
}

function mouseOutRiver(elem){
//toggle between colors
    if(elem.innerHTML=="hit"){
            elem.style.backgroundColor="rgb(255,107,107)";
        }else if(elem.innerHTML=="miss"){
            elem.style.backgroundColor="rgb(150,255,124)";  
        }else{
            elem.style.backgroundColor="rgb(150,150,255)";
        }
}


function setRowHandlers(rowClassName){
//listener loop, get listeners on all squares
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName(rowClassName);//produces array elements
    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
        rows[i].addEventListener( "mouseover", function(){mouseOverRiver(this)});
        rows[i].addEventListener( "click", function(){validate(this.id, fleet, "displayId", "victoryText");
        });
        
        rows[i].addEventListener( "mouseout", function(){mouseOutRiver(this)}); 
    }
}

//Reset, change position of the baots, resets bullets, change river squares back to normal, remove boats from graveyard, set "score back to 0"

function reset(fleet, square){

//change riversquares back to normal
for(var i=10;i<=19;i++){
    var id = "b"+i
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="rgb(150,150,255)";
}

//reset bullet count
turnCounter = 0;
console.log(turnCounter);

document.getElementById("displayId").innerHTML="Click on the squares and sink the boats with the least amount of shots.";
document.getElementById("victoryText").innerHTML="";

//change position boats
makeNewBoats();

skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:tinyBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: tinyBox2, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};
    
battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:largeBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: largeBox2, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: largeBox3, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};

fleet = [skiff, battleship];

//remove boats graveyard


/*
for(var j=0; j<boats.length; j++){
        for(var x=0; x<boats[j].spaces.length; x++){
                    boats[j].elem.style.display="none";
        }
}

*/
}



//color changes when mouseover
//click on river, change color hit 
//when boat sink, it appears in graveyardcontinue clicking river
//when sink boat, yellow turns into you win
//clicking same river spot doesnt cost extra spots
//shots updates for each shot. its hit or miss. It's  hitt!! you have used x shots.
//makes new game, its new game and randomizes positions of boat
//Reset, change position of the baots, resets bullets, change river squares back to normal, remove boats from graveyard, set "score back to 0"
/*reset change position boats
--clear out .spaces (memory cup in boat)


*first boat
--generate random number from 0 to (9 - (.length-1) ) allow boat to fit
-- fill in .spaces


*second boat
--generate random number from 0 to (9 - (.length-1) ) allow boat to fit
-- fill in .spaces
--check for a overlap
    --if (no overlap) start game
    --else choose new positions
    --else redo second boat


//memory cup that says battleships have length 3 skips length 2


*/
    </script>

    
</head>
<body>
<p><span id="displayId">Click on the squares and sink the boats with the least amount of shots.</span></p>
<p> <span id="victoryText"></span></p>
<table id="gameTable">
        <colgroup> <!-- colgroup allows you to define column properties-->
            <col width="10%"> <col width="10%">
            <col width="10%"> <col width="10%">
            <col width="10%"> <col width="10%">
            <col width="10%"> <col width="10%">
            <col width="10%"> <col width="10%">
        </colgroup>
    <!--alert pop up-->
    <tr class="titleRow" id="titleRow1"> 
        <th id="title" colspan="10">Battleship River Campaign</th> 
        <!--hardcode boats-->
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="landRow" id="landRow1">
        <td colspan=10></td>
     </tr>
     
    <tr class="waterRow" id="waterRow1">
        <td class="square" id="b10"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b11"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b12"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b13"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b14"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b15"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b16"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b17"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b18"></td>
        <td class="square" id="b19"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="landRow" id="landRow2">
        <td colspan=10></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>
<br>

 <div id="graveyard">
<p id="title">Ships Graveyard</p>
<p> <span class="deadShips" id="Battleship"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/NYEsI2j.jpg" height="100" width="100">Destroyer</span></p>
<p> <span class="deadShips" id="Skiff"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/PpXycYV.jpg" height="100" width="100">Canoe</span></p>
</div>


    <input type="button" id="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset(fleet, 'square')"></input>
    
    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Please produce a *minimal* amount of code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please see [mcve] - Provide a minimal amount of code to **reproduce** the issue. Not "some snippets of code which don't reproduce the issue" **plus** "absolutely all your code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, in your global variables, you will need to create the variable directly from the DOM element.

```
var skiff = document.querySelector("#Skiff");
skiff = {name: "Skiff", length:2, spaces:[{hitbox:tinyBox1, hitBefore:false},{hitbox: 
tinyBox2, hitBefore: false}], elem:"Skiff"};

//var battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:14, hitBefore:false}, 
    {hitbox: 15, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: 16, hitBefore: false}], 
     elem:"Battleship"};
 var battleship = document.querySelector("#Battleship");
 battleship ={name:"Battleship", length:3, spaces:[{hitbox:largeBox1, 
  hitBefore:false},{hitbox: largeBox2, hitBefore: false},{hitbox: largeBox3, 
  hitBefore: false}], elem:"Battleship"};

  var fleet = [];
```

Then on your window.onLoad function you need to call makeNewBoats() before the onLoad fleet is defined.

```
window.onload = function(){
makeNewBoats();
fleet[0].elem=document.getElementById(fleet[0].name);
fleet[1].elem=document.getElementById(fleet[1].name);

setRowHandlers("square");
```

}